# Copy/Paste unicode text from Firefox to Kitty terminal not working

Tags: firefox, archlinux, i3, kitty

(I'm currently on Arch with i3) When i try to copy some unicode text from Firefox to Kitty terminal for example:

昨日

it paste the text:

\u4f5c\u5bb6 \u6628\u65e5

if instead I select the same text (昨日) from Firefox and drag & drop it on the terminal , it paste it correctly as 昨日

The other way around always works , if i copy some emoji like  from the terminal to Firefox it works